# how to copy a file on the network in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file-upload, copy, nsfilemanager

I would like to copy the selected file from my computer to another computer on the same network. I tried to use NSFileManager but I was not successful. Could please help how to do it?

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSString * filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/test"]];
NSString * filePath2 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Shared/Test"]];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:filePath2 error:NULL];
[fileManager release];
```

Comment: If the network share is based on files then `NSFileManager` is the way to go, so please post more detail of the "not successful".

Comment: Like @trojanfoe said: what code did you use and what errors did you get?

Comment: That code won't compile as you are missing terminating `"` characters.

Comment: And if you use `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` rather than `[[NSManager alloc] init]`?

Comment: may bad I erased them accidentally I edited again

Comment: trojanfoe: [[NSFileManager alloc] init] is the by Apple recommended way I believe

Comment: You need to set that `NSError` pointer somewhere useful in order to get some diagnostics back to help solve your problem.

Comment: "Threading Considerations: The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely. However, if you use a delegate to receive notifications about the status of move, copy, remove, and link operations, you should create a unique instance of the file manager object, assign your delegate to that object, and use that file manager to initiate your operations." [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 suggestions:

1) as per the documentation, in this line the error should be "nil" not "NULL"

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:filePath2 error:NULL];
```

2) Maybe the code is not finding the files. I notice you do not have any file extension on the paths (maybe "test" should be "test.txt"?). Most files have an extension even if you can't see the extension in the Finder. Get Info on the file to check its extension and fix the code if that's the case.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I am using an openPanel to select the file. What I am trying to do is when the open button pressed the progress will start.

Comment: Did you try nil and did you log the error if it continues after trying nil?

Comment: yes but I am getting an error on the line of [fileManager release];It says release in unavailable.

Comment: OK, then remove the release line from your code. Also change "[[NSFileManager alloc] init]" to "[[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease]" or "[NSFileManager defaultManager]". I always use defaultManager instead of alloc/init anyway and it works without a hitch.

Comment: I worked after removing the release line! Thanks a lot for helping!